# Tailwind classes not applied

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've build an app using create-react-app and then installed tailwindcss and postcss. I've followed the config for applying tailwind but my classes still aren't being applied. I have tried specifying the files in the config but it's still picking up:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/App.jsx",
    "./src/*.{js,jsx,html}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,html}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,html}",
  ],
  theme: {
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

this is the index.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;
```

and this is the src/App.jsx where I apply the class:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <div className='flex bg-black'>
          <span>How to find us</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex'>
          <Component />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css` and have restarted the server, cleared cache and uninstalled and reinstalled tailwind but it still isn't working. Is there something I have missed?

Comment: I usually do an import of the css file as such `import './index.css';` in my App.jsx and it usually works fine

Comment: I've tried adding that in and it still won't apply the classes

Comment: Looking at [that documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app), it says "Create React App does not support custom PostCSS configurations and is incompatible with many important tools in the PostCSS ecosystem, like `postcss-import`.

We highly recommend using Vite, Parcel, Next.js, or Remix instead of Create React App."
Should have mentionned in my comment earlier that I was talking about a NextJS install, not a Create react app one. Never got any problem with tailwindcss + postcss + NextJS

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you node_modules the directory of /tailwindcss 
Then try to add this line to your src/App.jsx

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

Comment: I can see the node_module for tailwindcss and it all looks correct. I've added the import line to the App.jsx file and rebuilt and my problem is still persisting

Comment: I found an article here https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/tailwind-class-not-working Try to check dist/index.html link again